# Adding Items to wpf listbox where only one item varies in size?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have an idea of what I want to accomplish but am having difficulty accomplishing it. I want to add three items to a list box at a time. The left item in the row is a small image, the middle is a block of text and the last item is a small button. What can I use so that the image and button are always the same sizes, but the text could be anything from a single word or a few paragraphs and not warp the dimensions of the other 2 elements?

This is my last resort approach which kind of accomplishes this in an undesirable way:

```
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/defaultChar.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            img.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
            img.Height = 40;
            img.Width = 40;

            DockPanel dp = new DockPanel();
            DockPanel.SetDock(img, Dock.Left);
            dp.Children.Add(img);

            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            Button myButton = new Button {Content = "Edit" };
            sp.Children.Add(myButton);

            DockPanel.SetDock(myButton, Dock.Right);
            dp.Children.Add(sp);

            MyListbox.Items.Add(dp);

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            MyListbox.Items.Add(tb);
```

Comment: First of all, do not create UI elements in code behind. Declare a proper ItemTemplate in XAML, which contains a Grid with three columns, where the first and last column have fixed sizes. Or use a ListView with an appropriate GridView.

Comment: I need to add them programmatically because new rows will be added dynamically with different text content and different images.

Comment: @fnicke But this can also be done with XAML. That would even be more comfortable, in my opinion.

Comment: You should stop here and first read a good WPF book (e.g. *WPF Unleashed* by Adam Nathan) or at least this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Comment: I figured it out. I put a stackpanel inside a scrollviewer and created a method that adds the three elements to a horizontal stackpanel which gets added to the main panel in the scrollviewer each time. Thank you for the suggestions, but I prefer to avoid XAML when possible.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a few possible solutions. It depends a little on the circumstances. At first glance, I would try to pack everything into a `Grid` with three columns:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Images/defaultChar.jpg"
                       Stretch="Fill" Width="40" Height="40"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyText}"/>

                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Edit" Command="{Binding MyEditCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is XAML now, but of course it can also be recreated in C#.